# Diferença entre os operadores yield e yield* no ECMAScript 6.0 "Harmony"?

Tags: javascript, generators, yield, ecmascript-6

Estou estudando o uso de *generators* no ECMAScript 6.0 *"Harmony"*.

Já consegui entender o seu funcionamento básico, como a declaração através da sintaxe `function* () { ... }` e da produção de valores através do operador `yield`.

Entretanto, ainda não consegui encontrar uma explicação satisfatória para o funcionamento do operador `yield*`. Na [página sobre *generators* da wiki oficial da linguagem](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3agenerators) é inclusive disponibilizado o seguinte código, que seria equivalente a esse operador, em termos do operador `yield`:

```
let (g = <<expr>>) {
    let received = void 0, send = true, result = void 0;
    try {
        while (true) {
            let next = send ? g.send(received) : g.throw(received);
            try {
                received = yield next;
                send = true;
            } catch (e) {
                received = e;
                send = false;
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        if (!isStopIteration(e))
            throw e;
        result = e.value;
    } finally {
        try { g.close(); } catch (ignored) { }
    }
    result
}
```

Ainda assim não consegui entender claramente o propósito ou o efeito obtido com o uso desse operador. Alguém saberia me explicar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ainda estou engatinhando em ES6, mas pelo que entendi o `yield*` é necessário quando você quer delegar o `yield` para outro generator. Achei um [exemplo simples](https://github.com/JustinDrake/node-es6-examples):

```javascript
let delegatedIterator = (function* () {
  yield 'Hello!';
  yield 'Bye!';
}());

let delegatingIterator = (function* () {
  yield 'Greetings!';
  yield* delegatedIterator;
  yield 'Ok, bye.';
}());

// Prints "Greetings!", "Hello!", "Bye!", "Ok, bye."
for(let value of delegatingIterator) {
  console.log(value);
}
```

Repare que `yield* delegatedIterator;` consome completamente o `delegatedIterator`. Se você utilizasse `yield delegatedIterator.next()`, a saída seria `"Greetings!", "Hello!", "Ok, bye."`.

Bom, foi assim que entendi, mas como disse ainda não estou muito seguro em ES6. E não achei uma ferramenta para testar isso...

Comment: Oh. Acho que finalmente consegui entender a "delegação" possível com o `yield*`! Muito obrigado :) 

Só para confirmar, na sua explicação você quis dizer `yield delegatedIterator.next()`, certo? (No caso que produziria somente um elemento.)

Comment: Ops, sim! Vou corrigir. Curiosidade: em que ferramenta posso testar esse código? Tentei no FF e no node 0.8, deu erro de sintaxe.

Comment: O suporte a generators está sendo testado no node 0.11, através do *flag* `--harmony`, mas pelo que eu sei, ainda não suportam o operador `yield*`. O Facebook recentemente lançou uma ferramenta que traduz automaticamente código ES6 com generators para código ES5 válido, chamada [regenerator](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator). Um colega criou um módulo que transparentemente chama esse tradutor para rodar seu código no node, chamado [gnode](https://github.com/TooTallNate/gnode). Ele funciona com o 0.8, e suporta o `yield*`. É o que eu tenho usado nos meus testes.

Comment: Obrigado, @MarcoAurélio! Vou experimentar esse módulo, e também atualizar meu node.

Comment: Só lembrando que o node 0.11 é uma versão experimental (O node segue a convenção de impar = beta, par = release) Você pode usar a ferramenta `n`, (https://github.com/visionmedia/n) para manter várias versões do node instaladas, e alternar entre elas. (Eu só não sei se funciona no Windows.)

Comment: Valeu mesmo. Uso Mac, e acabei de atualizar para a 0.10.22 (stable) via `n`. @MarcoAurélio